# Border Box and overflow causing problems

Tags: html, css, overflow, viewport, hidden

If I can ask you to [swing by Codepen:](http://codepen.io/Ktraving/pen/rWZymK) and have look in full screen (media queries arent done) you will notice I am having issues solving the layout without using overflow:hidden.

You will see that

a) the Some line and icons drop into the green section
b) the blue section drop below the two other sections despite border-box'ing

If I enable overflow:hidden globally, the layout shows the way I want it. But it has a lot of unwanted effects, and hinders the use of a nice burger nav menu.

Question

A) Why dont the three sections align up, despite using float and viewport set to 33.33vw? I imaine this to be the key problem.

```css
/* Globale styles */
/* En af vores store udfordringer er og har været, overflow:hidden; */
/* Den er afgørende for at få forsiden til at fungere godt */
/* Men den hæmmer samtidig en masse andre muligheder */

* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;  /* If overflow is used, the layout works. If not, it completely disintegrates  */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-width:0;
}

/* Menulinje i toppen, simpel text */

nav
{
 background-color:white;
 height:30px;
 Padding-left:30px;
 Padding-top:5px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 width:50vw;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 float:left;
}


/* Ikoner til sociale medier */

.somebar
{
 background-color:white;
 height:30px;
 Padding-right:30px;
 Padding-top:5px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 width:50vw;
 text-align:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

/* Farver til sociale medier og ikoner */

a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

a:hover
{
 color:red;
}

nav > a
{
 color:black;
 padding-right:7px;
}

nav > a:hover
{
 color:red;
}

/* Sidefoden, simpel text */


footer
{
 text-transform:uppercase;
 clear:both;
 background-color:white;
 height:30px;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-right:30px;
 text-align:right;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:black;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


.img_list
{
 color:white;
 list-style-type:none;
}

/* Menu styling, der er lidt tricky for at tage hensyn til vores layout */
/* Den globale overflow:hidden forhindrer brugen er burgermenu */








/* iphone størrelse */

@media only screen and (max-device-height: 640px) {

 .colleft
 {
  background-image:url('images/wide_jump.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center center;
  height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(33vh - 80px);
  text-align:center; 
 }

 .colcenter
 {
  background-image:url('images/wide_kid.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center center;
  height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(33vh - 20px);
  text-align:center;   
 }

 .colright
 {
  background-image:url('images/wide_riders.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center center;
  height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(33vh - 20px);
  text-align:center;   
 }


 .colright > h1
 {
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
 }

}

/* ipad størrelse */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-height: 1224px) {

 .colleft
 {
  background-image:url('images/wide_jump.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center center;
  height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(33vh - 20px);
  text-align:center;
 }

 .colcenter
 {
  background-image:url('images/wide_kid.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center center;
  height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(33vh - 20px);
  text-align:center;   
 }

 .colright
 {
  background-image:url('images/wide_riders.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center center;
  height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(33vh - 20px);
  text-align:center;   
 }

 .colcenter_content
 {
  background-color:lightgrey;
  min-height:height:calc(33vh - 40px);
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  padding:20px;
 } 

 .colright_content
 {
  background-color:lightgrey;
  min-height:calc(100vh - 80px);  
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  padding:20px;

 } 


 .art_center
 {
     line-height: 1.2;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }

}


/* Standard pc og skærmne */

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {

 h1
 {
  font-size:30px;
  margin:0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:30px;
  color:white; 
 }

 .h1_back
 {
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px; /* future proofing */
  -khtml-border-radius: 50px;
  background-color:black;
  display:inline-block;
  width:70%;
  height:80px;
  opacity: 0.5;
 }

 .colleft
 {
  width:33.3333vw;
  background-image:url('images/high_jump.jpg');;
  float:left;
  height:calc(100vh - 80px);
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 30px;
  line-height:calc(100vh - 80px);
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red;
 }

 .colcenter
 {
  width:33.3333vw;
  background-image:url('images/high_kid.jpg');
  float:left;
  height:calc(100vh - 80px);  
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  line-height:calc(100vh - 80px);
  text-align:center;
  background-color:green; 
 }

 .colright
 {
  width:33vw;
  background-image:url('images/high_riders.jpg');
  float:left;
  height:calc(100vh - 80px);  
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 0px;
  line-height:calc(100vh - 80px);
  text-align:center;
  background-color:blue;
 }


 .leftie  /* rette op på border, når kolonne style bruges på subpages */
 {
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 30px !important;
 }


 .colcenter_content
 {
  width:33.3333vw;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  float:left;
  height:calc(100vh - 80px);  
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-left:40px;
  padding-right:40px;  
 }

 .colcenter_content h1
 {
  font-size:30px;
  color:black;
  margin-bottom:20px;
 }


 .colright_content
 {
  width:33.3333vw;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  float:left;
  height:calc(100vh - 80px);  
  border-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px 30px 0px 0px;
  padding:20px;
 } 

 .video_style
 {
  height:calc((100vh - 260px)/3);
  margin-bottom:20px;
  width:100%;
  border-width:5px;
  border-style:line;
  border-color:white;
 }

  .art_center
 {
     line-height: 1.2;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle 
    }

}
```

```html
<!-- Sidehoved -->

 <header>
  <nav>
   <a href="#">Forside</a>
   <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
   <a href="#">Formalia</a>   
  </nav>
  <div class="somebar">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/K%C3%B8ge-BMX-Klub-226506560882006/?fref=ts">facebook&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   <a href="http://www.youtube.com">&nbsp;&nbsp;youtube&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
 </header>

<!-- 

 I modsætning til de øvrige sider, har forsiden et unikt udseende, hvor billederne skal dominere.

 Venstre kolonne

-->

 <a href="kom_og_moed.htm" class="query_left">
  <section class="colleft">
   <div class="h1_back">
    <h1>Kom og mød os</h1>
   </div>
   <ul class="img_list">
    <li>Prøv BMX helt gratis!</li>
    <li>Snak med vores trænere</li>
    <li>Hvornår træner vi</li>        
   </ul>
  </section>
 </a>

<!---

 Center kolonne indhold

-->
```

Comment: Can you try rephrasing? I don't see any icons and what do you mean by the the Some line?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS to what you already have

```
header {width: 100vw}
.somebar {
    float: right;
}   
header ~ a {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using flexbox instead of float. It will also save a lot of time and effort with your media queries.
Wrap your three divs in a container and set it to

```
.container {display: flex;}
```

Then set the width of the three children to 33.33% and they will line up next to each other and fill the whole screen.  They will also automatically adjust as the screen grows or shrinks.

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)  is a great resource for flexbox.

As a side note, I would recommend keeping your code as DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as possible. If you write the CSS to work on a certain size screen you only need to use @media to change the things that need to be changed. For example, you only need to set the colours once as they remain the same no matter the size of the screen.